# Why do English translations use the name "Eve" rather than "Chava"?

Tags: names, parashat-bereishit, translation, english, eve-chava

When the Bible is translated into English, most Hebrew names are simply transliterated into Roman characters.

In a few cases though, a completely different name is used.

In the case of Hadassah/Esther, the scripture explicitly gives both names,
and thereafter consistently uses one and not the other.

But "חַוָּ֑ה", for instance, isn't transliterated into "Chavah".
It is instead given only as "Eve", even in Jewish-sponsored translations of Genesis.

> And the man named his wife Eve, because she was the mother of all life.
>
> וַיִּקְרָ֧א הָֽאָדָ֛ם שֵׁם אִשְׁתּ֖וֹ חַוָּה כִּי
>      הִ֥וא הָֽיְתָ֖ה אֵ֥ם כָּל־חָֽי
>
> — [Bereishit - Genesis - Chapter 3 (Parshah Bereishit) - Tanakh Online - Torah - Bible](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8167/jewish/Chapter-3.htm#v20)

Is there a technical or historical reason why it was done this way?

Comment: In Greek there is no Chet

Comment: Cf. Yechezkel / Ezekiel

Comment: Possible dupe or related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/65134/7303

Comment: "most Hebrew names are simply transliterated into Roman characters" This is not true as far as I know. Most English translations use English translations of names consistently. Your linked edition also uses Abram, Noah, Moses, Aaron, Pharoh, Balaam, Phinehas, etc.

Comment: @YaacovDeane, it's not really a duplicate, but about when she received the name.

Comment: @kouty, Latin rather than Greek I think.  Part of my confusion that resulted in this question was because in English, "Eve" is only one syllable.  In most other languages it is two syllables, which makes the mapping to the original Hebrew more obvious. [Eve (name) - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eve_(name)) says: "*derived from the Latin name Eva, in turn originating with the Hebrew חַוָּה*". (Those that avoid nudity should disable images before viewing this Wikipedia page.)

Comment: Is this question, "why is the word transliterated this way" or "why would a Jewish publisher rely on this transliteration instead of using a more exact one"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From here](https://www.quora.com/According-to-the-Hebrew-Bible-Adam-called-his-wife-Chava-%D7%97%D6%B7%D7%95%D6%BC%D6%B8%D7%94-because-she-was-the-mother-of-all-living-things-Why-does-the-English-transliteration-used-in-Christian-Bibles-employ-the-word-Eve-for-the-nameChava-%D7%97%D6%B7%D7%95%D6%BC%D6%B8%D7%94):

> "The Septuagint renders חַוָּה as Ζωή (Zo-ay or Zoe -- literally meaning "life" חיּה ). But the name became Ἕυα (Evah or Eve) in other Greek translations. The Tyndale uses Heua, which is related to Eua -- where we get Eve. Eue or Euan in Greek could either be a simple mis-transliteration, or perhaps the Eu- prefix could hint at the Greek meaning "good." The Vulgate uses "Hava". The letter "ח" in Hebrew is often softened to an English "H" by people who cannot pronounce the harsher KH sound with their throat."

The Vulgate was authored by Jerome, one of only two Church Fathers who knew Hebrew, therefore he was able to suggest a transliteration that was much more closer to the original. However, the reason Eve became the more popular version is likely because most people, not knowing Hebrew like Jerome, had difficulty even with his version, necessitating a further softening of the H to an E. From Eva it somehow became Eve.

Comment: I feel like there should be a mention that the letter vav used to be waw and there was a consonant shift in greek and latin from v to w in a lot of cases. Somehow Esau stayed Esau and didn't shift to Esav

Comment: The Septuagint gives   Ἕυα in Gen 4. It presumably gives Ζωή in Gen 3 so that ὅτι αὕτη μήτηρ πάντων τῶν ζώντων makes sense.

Comment: @Aaron I think you mean /w/ to /v/. That is, the letter "v" used to make a /w/ sound, and it shifted. Similarly, the upsilon υ shifted in certain contexts (often in the diphthong ευ) to a fricative.

Comment: Ἕυα is not a mis-transliteration. The rough breathing at the beginning adds an /h/ sound, and vav ו was contemporaneously pronounced /w/. So /ħawwɔ/ in Hebrew becomes /hɛwa/. This eventually becomes /ɛβa/ or /eβa/ as the rough breathing is lost (just like word-initial ה was lost in many dialects of Hebrew) and as /ew/ became /eβ/.

Comment: @magicker72 I didn't understand how you get from an "ah" sound in Chava to an "ee" sound in Cheeva. It dies in fact sound like a mistranslation.

Comment: @Harel13 The letters ע and ח can color vowels as *e* in the Hebrew represented by Greek transliterations (much like the חטף פתח and פתת גנובה in masoretic Hebrew on the letters אהח"ע - and incidentally the פתח is also pronounced identically to the סגול in Yemenite pronunciation). For example: חוילה -> Ευιλατ (Genesis 2:11), באר שבע -> Βηρσαβεε (Amos 8:14)

Answer (score 1):

The standard seems to be set by the fact that the name has a commonly accepted translated version.

Indeed Artscroll writes this explicitly in their "Translation And Commentary" introduction to the Stone chumash. First they point out how they blended Sephardi vowel and Ashkenazi pronunciations resulting in Akeidas Yitzchak and not Akeidat Izhak or Akeidas Yitzchok. 
Afterwards, at the very end of that introduction they write:

> In the translation of the Text, however, we have generally followed the commonly accepted English usage, such as Abraham, Moses, Methuselah, and so on.